# Any way to stream a browser-like instance to a client using JS?

Tags: javascript, browser, websocket, streaming

I'm trying to stream a browser like instance from a Linux server and receive that from my client and be able to control that browser from my client remotely. Sort of like a TeamViewer but only a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use https://xpra.org/ It's somewhat complex, but it is performant and works inside a browser.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you !

Comment: tho would it be possible to have many users having multiple clients, having multiple different chrome browsers?